# Background process does not show up in ps

Tags: ps, background-process

I used ssh to start a dotnet app as background job on a remote server

```
dotnet MyApp.dll &
```

I confirmed, that the app was running and then terminated the ssh session.

Now I want to kill this background job, but I can't find its PID anywhere. Neither `jobs` nor `ps -a` nor `ps -e` nor `pgrep -i MyApp` nor `top` lists the launched process. I also looked for something like `dotnet` but this also does not yield any running processes.
I know for sure, that it is still running as it still sends data to an external target.

Why does this process not show up anywhere although it is running? How can I stop it without rebooting the server?

Comment: If it doesn't show up on ps, it's not there. Reboot won't change anything.